# Significato dell’espressione “avere il minimo alto”

Tags: meaning, idioms

I have heard the following sentence in an Italian TV series:

> Sono 'sti cazzo de Adami che hanno il minimo alto.

The speaker is a gangster and he is talking about one of his men, which was beaten up by a guy from the rival Adami family the night before. What does "avere il minimo alto" mean? "to have a short fuse", "to get angry easily"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is a metaphor that suggests  they can  easily get angry. The expression is generally used  for motorcycles whose “minimo” engine level  is the level at which the engine can run when it is [idle.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_(engine))

(Wikipedia)

Comment: It's used not only for motorcycles, but also for cars (and more generally for anything with an engine). In fact I'd say it's more common for cars, but that probably depends from your personal experiences :)

Comment: Sì, io associo il minimo del motore più facilmente ad una moto che ad un’auto, forse perché nelle auto tende ad essere più stabile mentre nelle moto e specialmente nei motorini deve essere regolato più spesso.

Comment: Il -1 è per via del discorso moto/macchina?

Comment: Io ho dato un upvote, non ho idea di perché qualcuno voterebbe -1

Comment: @Gio: Can you please add the link to the source?

Comment: Non ho capito bene il senso della lunga citazione in cui non si parla di lingua italiana e quindi non è mai menzionata la parola “minimo”, tanto meno in senso figurato.

Comment: @Charo - it is from Wikipedia. Unlikely I can’t add the source. I am using  the app on the phone. Sorry. But     what’s the problem? Should the answer be in Italian?

Comment: @Gio: No, that's not a problem. It's that I can't find the source of the quotation.